# Custom HTML element extending another custom element

Tags: html, custom-element

I have a custom HTML tag `<fancy-foo>` that I would like to extend the functionality of. Some of the `<fancy-foo>` elements would be extended using the `pretty-bar` custom element, so that I can use them in my HTML as

```
<fancy-foo is="pretty-bar">
    <!-- content -->
</fancy-foo>
```

so, I define classes `FancyFoo` and `PrettyBar`, define the `fancy-foo` element and extend it using `pretty-bar`, like so:

```
class FancyFoo extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

class PrettyBar extends FancyFoo {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

window.customElements.define('fancy-foo', FancyFoo);
window.customElements.define('pretty-bar', PrettyBar, {extends: 'fancy-foo'});
```

Sadly, Google Chrome spits out the error

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': "fancy-foo" is a valid custom element name

That's an odd error. Strangely, it says "fancy-foo" *is* a valid custom element name; I know that, but why should that throw an error?

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot extend Custom Elements that way (with `{extends: '...'}`). You can only extend *buit-in* (= standard) HTML elements.

If you want to design `PrettyBar` as an extension of `FancyFoo`, you'll need to define it as an *autonomous* custom element:

```
class PrettyBar extends FancyFoo {...}
window.customElements.define('pretty-bar', PrettyBar)
```

Same thing for the HTML tag:

```
<pretty-bar></pretty-bar>
```

Comment: That makes sense. Still, the error message is oddly worded, but I guess that's irrelevant.

Comment: I get "autonomous custom elements must extend HTMLElement" :(. Note that, in my case, FancyFoo is extending HTMLDivElement.

Comment: @ESL but did you add `{extends:'div'}` as a third parameter?

Comment: Yes, with and without arises different exceptions. Apparently, it is not allowed to reextend an extension of a non-HTMLElement element class and implement it as a custom element. I don't understand why, and I need to read docs and docs to find that.

Comment: It's odd. If one can extend HTMLDivElement and implement it as a custom element, why can't I do the same with an extension of that class???

Answer (score 2):

This way it is possible to create correct inheritance chain. Extended built-in element's class is further extensible:

```js
class FancyFoo extends HTMLDivElement {
    constructor() {super();}
}

class PrettyBar extends FancyFoo {
    constructor() {super();}
}

window.customElements.define('fancy-foo', FancyFoo, {extends: 'div'});

window.customElements.define('pretty-bar', PrettyBar, {extends: 'div'});
```

```html
<div is="fancy-foo"></div>
<div is="pretty-bar"></div>
```

`customElements.define` determines the is-name, constructor, and built-in's tag-name, if used this way. It does not need to know the exact constructor chain, provided it leads to the call of the appropriate built-in's constructor. You can establish the inheritance by extending one class by another.

Style it to override the div behavior, or use a more appropriate built-in element as base.